# How to select lowest level in hierarchy from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with parent/child relationship:

```
Table A
Column Id int
Column Parent_Id int
Column Description text
```

An example set of data would be:

```
999, NULL, 'Corp.'
998, 999, 'Div1',
997, 999, 'Div2', 
510, 998, 'Child Div1A',
110, 997, 'Child Div2A',
120, 997, 'Child Div2B',
```

My query needs to return the lowest set of children, given a parent. So, for example, if given 999, I would return 510, 110, 120. But given 997, I would return only 110 and 120. If given 110, nothing would return. I can't figure out how to format my query quite correctly. I started by JOIN-ing the table on itself, but it seems like that would only get me 1 level down when I actually neeed to go N-levels down.

Comment: For recursive descent in SQL Server, you'll need to use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Declare @t Table(ID int,Parent_ID int,Description varchar(20))

insert into @t values(999, NULL, 'Corp.')
insert into @t values(998, 999, 'Div1')
insert into @t values(997, 999, 'Div2')
insert into @t values(510, 998, 'Child Div1A')
insert into @t values(110, 997, 'Child Div2A')
insert into @t values(120, 997, 'Child Div2B')

;WITH Rollups AS (
    SELECT Id, Parent_Id, Description 
    FROM @t WHERE ID = 999
    UNION ALL
    SELECT parent.Id, parent.Parent_Id, child.Description
    FROM @t parent 
    INNER JOIN Rollups child ON child.Id = parent.Parent_Id
)
SELECT *
FROM Rollups
Where not Exists(Select * from @t where Parent_Id=Rollups.ID)
```

Comment: @bummi You are a rockstar!! Legendary answer!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this but I think it's what you need - using a `CTE` with `UNION` (I've cut it down from a more complex example that I use):

```
;WITH CTE (ChildID, [Text], ParentID)
AS
(
    SELECT ChildID, [Text], ParentID
    FROM Table1
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL --or = @ParentID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.ChildID, T1.[Text], T1.ParentID
    FROM Table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN CTE
    ON T1.ParentID = CTE.ChildID
)
SELECT ChildID, [Text]
FROM CTE
```

Comment: This is nice (thanks!) but there's one case where it doesn't work...if I switch the condition from "ParentId IS NULL" to "ParentId = `@ParentID`", the case that doesn't work is when `@ParentID` is the highest level. It returns the immediate children when it should return only the lowest levels. @bummi's answer below adds another conditional that resolves this. Thanks for the help.